# Laravel : Validate fields if they have the same value

Tags: php, laravel

I have an order detail that includes multiple product listings. I want to ensure that users cannot select the same product for a single order. For example, here is the result of the dd($request) function.

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#45
#parameters: array:16 [
  "_token" => "El3iq45CsoEPRXxwaAOv072O0bWARb5WUNx3Lmfe"
  "warehouse_id" => "1"
  "customer_id" => "1"
  "order_date" => "2023-08-24 19:20"
  "shipping_address" => "q"
  "product_id0" => "1"
  "qty0" => "1"
  "stock_outstanding0" => "99"
  "unit_price0" => "65000"
  "total_price0" => "65000"
  "count_item" => "1"
  "product_id1" => "1"
  "qty1" => "1"
  "stock_outstanding1" => "100"
  "unit_price1" => "65000"
  "total_price1" => "65000"
]
}
```

As you can see, there are two product IDs, product_id0 and product_id1, that have the same value.

```
"product_id0" => "1"
"product_id1" => "1"
```

I want a validator to check if it has the same value, it will abort the order. I have implemented validation, but it still seems to be incorrect. This is because if product_id0 and product_id1 have different values, such as

```
"product_id0" => "1"
"product_id1" => "2"
```

It keep send the message **Validation Work**

Here the validation i made

```
$isValid = true;

    for ($g = 0; $g <= $request->count_item; $g++) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'warehouse_id' => 'required',
            'customer_id' => 'required',
            'order_date' => 'required',
            'shipping_address' => 'required',
            "product_id{$g}.*" => 'distinct',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($isValid) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Validation Work',
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'Validation Failed',
        ]);
    }
```

Also i made another validation but still dont work

```
$tempId = [];
    $tempArray = [];

    for ($g=0; $g <= $request->count_item; $g++) { 
        $tempId[] = $request['product_id' . $g];

        if(in_array($tempId, $tempArray)){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'True validation work',
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'False validation failed',
            ]);
            $tempArray[] = $tempId;
            dd($tempArray);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're validating each product at a time, so it won't be able to match it against the others. I would probably suggest building up a product validation array, then validating that, instead.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distinct` rule only works on arrays of values. You're not using an array, as you've put each value in it's own variable (`product_id0` vs `product_id[0]`).

I would suggest changing your request to use an array so you can take advantage of the `distinct` rule.

Change the name on your input to `product[0][id]` and `product[1][id]`, and then your validation rule would be `product.*.id => 'distinct'`. Also, you'd have a valid array of products to loop through, instead of having to dynamically build variable names.

---

If you can't modify the request coming in, you could build up a new array to validate on the server side. However, if you do this, the error bag keys won't match the inputs on the screen, so you'd need to account for that if you're trying to show error messages for the fields on the screen.

```
// Build your new data array.
$data = $request->all();
for ($g = 0; $g <= $request->count_item; $g++) {
    $data['product'][$g]['id'] = $data["product_id{$g}"];
}

// Now validate the data array.
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'warehouse_id' => 'required',
    'customer_id' => 'required',
    'order_date' => 'required',
    'shipping_address' => 'required',
    'product.*.id' => 'distinct',
]);
```

---

Finally, if neither of these is a valid option, you can use the `different` validation. This will be a little trickier if you can have a dynamic amount of products. The `different` validation lets you specify that one field must be different than another, so you'd need to specify that p0 is different than p1, p2, ..., pN, and then p1 is different than p2, p3, ..., pN, etc.

```
$rules = [
    'warehouse_id' => 'required',
    'customer_id' => 'required',
    'order_date' => 'required',
    'shipping_address' => 'required',
];
// Outer loop goes from 0 -> N-1
for ($g = 0; $g < $request->count_item; $g++) {
    // Inner loop goes from Outer+1 to N
    for ($h = $g + 1; $h <= $request->count_item; $h++) {
        $rules["product_id{$g}"] = "different:product_id{$h}";
    }
}

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

*NB: all untested code. May contain syntax/logic errors.*

Comment: Ahh, i should mention this earlier on top of my post. To be know, this is'nt my project i just helping my friend. But yeah that was corrent i should change my input on the blade to array. But there's gonna be another problem because there was already DOM like this

```var counter = 0;
counter++;
'<select name="product_id' + counter +>```

Comment: Is there alternate sollusion instead using distinct?

Comment: @Alberiansyah I've updated my answer with a couple more options.

Comment: @Alberiansyah That said, best solution would be to change the DOM to `'<select name="product[' + counter + '][id]"` to get your array format in the request. Using that format, you can group all the rest of the related fields together, too (ex: `name="product[' + counter + '][qty]"`)

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying today as I just had the chance. I tried option 2 and it worked, thank you, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're validating each product at a time, so it won't be able to match it against the others. Instead, build up the validation array before you actually validate it. `product_id{$g}` is a single item, so don't use `.*`, since that's used for arrays.

```
$rules = [
    'warehouse_id' => 'required',
    'customer_id' => 'required',
    'order_date' => 'required',
    'shipping_address' => 'required',
];
for ($g = 0; $g <= $request->count_item; $g++) {
    $rules["product_id{$g}"] = 'distinct';
}
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules );

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $isValid = false;
}
```

You could also turn your products in your form to be an array with `products[]`, then use `'products.*'=> 'distinct'` instead of building up the rules based on the item count.

Comment: I try your code, but the response still Validation Work, even the product_id has different value.

Comment: But, i will try a second one.

Comment: Nope, is still giving false at `$validator->fails()`

Comment: But on dd() it was correct ```array:6 [
  "warehouse_id" => "required"
  "customer_id" => "required"
  "order_date" => "required"
  "shipping_address" => "required"
  "product_id0" => "distinct"
  "product_id1" => "distinct"
]```